# Django signal reciever not called after connecting to pre_delete signal

Tags: python, django, signals

#### Goal

I'm trying to implement a voting system that tracks when a user makes a vote on a specific object in the database. I'm tracking this using an intermediate `UserVote`model with a foreign key to the object that actually contains all the votes. Whenever the `UserVote` gets deleted I want to remove the vote on the related object.

#### What I've tried

[Since bulk deletes do not call the `model.delete()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#delete), I want to accomplish the above by listening to the `pre_delete` signal.

When I test the below receiver function using the Django test runner, everything behaves as expected

```
from myapp.models.users import UserVote
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(pre_delete)
def user_vote_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if sender in UserVote.__subclasses__():
        # remove the vote from the related model
```

#### Problem

When I call `delete()` on a model instance in views.py, the function is not called. If I add print statements to the receiver function as below, none of the statements are printed.

```
from myapp.models.users import UserVote
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(pre_delete)
def user_vote_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('function called')
    if sender in UserVote.__subclasses__():
        print('condition met')
        # remove the vote from the related model
```

I've read through the [Signal Documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) and I haven't found the source of the problem. I've put the receiver function in `myapp.signals` and in `myapp.models.users` and the behavior is the same. I have a feeling I've done something stupid and haven't realized it. Can anyone shed some light on what could be going wrong? I'm using Django 2.2.

#### Code

```
# models.records.py
...


class Record(models.Model):
    ...
    # some functions for all Record subclasses
    ....


class Author(Record):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(
        Comment,
        through='ForumComment',
        through_fields=('author', 'comment'),
    )
    ...
    # some functions specific to this
    ....

...
# more records
...
```

```
# models.comments.py
...


class RecordComment(models.Mode):
    text = label = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
    # some methods
    ...


class AuthorComment(RecordComment):
    ...
    # methods specific to AuthorComment
    ...

...
# more RecordComment subclass
...


class Comment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    up_votes = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    down_votes = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)


class ForumComment(Comment):
    author = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='related record')
    comment = models.ForeignKey(AuthorComment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
...
# more types of comments
...
```

```
# models.users.py
...


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class UserVote(models.Model):
    """shared fields and functions for UserVote models"""
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    DOWN_VOTE = 'DOWN'
    UP_VOTE = 'UP'
    VOTE_CHOICES = [
        (DOWN_VOTE, 'Down vote'),
        (UP_VOTE, 'Up vote'),
    ]
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.CharField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES, default=UP_VOTE, max_length=255)
    ...
    # methods to handle voting
    ...


class ForumCommentUserVote(UserVote):
    forum_comment = models.ForeignKey('myapp.ForumComment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['forum_comment', 'user'], name='unique_author_tag_assignment_user_vote')
        ]
    ...
    # some more methods
    ...
...
# more UserVote subclasses
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you app app.py file add import for signals it should look like this

```
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

and in the settings.py you should add your app like this

```
'users.apps.UsersConfig',
```

this should trigger the pre_delete signal, :D i spent a whole day once thinking i did something wrong when i actually i just forgot these 2 lol

Comment: Wow I'm dumb, there actually is a note about the ready function in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions). For anyone testing your signals, make sure you [guard them from duplication by adding a dispatch_uid](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals)